# Redis Lua debugger: disable scientific notation for large numbers

Tags: debugging, redis, lua

When debugging a Lua script using the [Redis Lua debugger](https://redis.io/topics/ldb) I've noticed that large numbers are displayed in scientific (exponential) notation:

```lua
redis.debug(26792254717.283333)
```

```sh
<debug> line 1: 2.67923e+10
```

Is possible somehow to disable the scientific notation when debugging on the console?

Answer (score 2):

This actually globally occurs on multiple Lua compilers by default.

I have found a solution to this issue I have been suffering with too previously. It would not give the number as a number value datatype but rather as a string.
I'm also not sure where I found this solution, but I have it.

```
redis.debug(string.format("%.0f", 26792254717.283333)) -- Will return as string
```

When retrieving it as number it would unfortunately give it has exponent scientific value. Alternatively, you can get rid of that 0

I also have another solution I have which involves some math but sometimes returns inaccurate values ranging from around .000001.

Edit: Nvm, sorry, just realized this get rid of the decimal values too. Forgot to try that out. I will edit my post once I find the answer.